# argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Window

Tags: python-2.7

Not sure if what I am trying to do is wrong or impossible. Here is my code:

```
import pygame

class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, (width, height), color, cap=' '):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.cap = cap
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.width, self.height))
    def display(self):
        self.screen
        #screen = 
        pygame.display.set_caption(self.cap)
        self.screen.fill(self.color)

class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, window, (x, y), color, size, thick=None):
        self.window = window
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.thick = thick
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.window, self.color, (self.x, self.y),
                           self.size, self.thick)

def main():
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)
    screen = Window((600, 600), black, 'Pong')
    screen.display()
    ball = Ball(screen, (300, 300), white, 5)
    ball.draw()

    running = True

    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False

        pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.quit()
main()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\acmil\Desktop\Team 7\newPongLib.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\acmil\Desktop\Team 7\newPongLib.py", line 36, in main
    ball.draw()
  File "C:\Users\acmil\Desktop\Team 7\newPongLib.py", line 28, in draw
self.size, self.thick)
```

TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not Window

I don't understand if i make a Window object why it won't draw a ball to the screen. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your **Ball** class to the following:

```
class Ball(object):
    def __init__(self, window, (x, y), color, size, thick=0):
        self.window = window
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.thick = thick
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(self.window.screen, self.color, (self.x, self.y),
                           self.size, self.thick)
```

I made two modifications to your code.

- First, as for the error you were getting, you were passing in a custom `Window` object that you had defined instead of the pygame's `Screen` object that pygame was expecting. Check out the documentation on this function [here](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle).
- Second, your original constructor defined `thick=None` by default, but that pygame function expects an int, so I changed it to `thick=0`.

It should work after these two changes. Let me know if you still are having issues!